# How to make progressively overlapping circles based on percentage value in R?

Tags: r

I would like to have or make a function that generate progressively overlapping circles based on percentage overlap value. Say,

overlap.circle(1)

Would give:

[image: Full overlap]

overlap.circle(0)

Would give:

[image: Zero overlap]

overlap.circle(50)

Would give something like:

[image: About 50% overlap]

How can I create such a function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without creating your own function with the `VennDiagram` package:

```r
library(VennDiagram)

# The 3rd value is percent overlap
venn.plot <- draw.pairwise.venn(100, 100, 50, c("Self", "Other"))

# Clear the plot
grid.newpage()
```

If you really wanted it to be that specific function call:

```r
overlap.circle <- function(po){
  grid.newpage()
  VennDiagram::draw.pairwise.venn(100, 100, po, c("Self", "Other"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was quick and excellent! I stumbled on VennDiagram package but didn't perceive it could suit my needs. Now I see it does! Thanks a lot for the specific function call too, it's very appreciated, handy, and useful!

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, I would like to post an updated answer. There is now a package to do this:

```r
library(rempsyc)
overlap_circle(3.5)
```

[image]

```r
overlap_circle(6.84)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The middle number on the figure is the percentage overlap. The number that we feed the function is not a percentage, but a score from the inclusion of self in the other scale, which goes from 1-7 (where 1 = 0% overlap, and 7 = 85% overlap).

Full tutorial: https://rempsyc.remi-theriault.com/articles/circles.html

**Disclaimer: I am the package author and have used @Brigadeiro's answer to write this function!**